# Compilation time message (after preprocessor) to use with `if constexpr`

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am using an `if constexpr` to test the presence of a method in a class. If the method is not present, I wish to tell the user the function was ignored and he should implement it but it is not mandatory.

The idea is to give a message similar to `#warning` but the preprocessor is processed before the template thus this will never work.

Is there any **compilation time** feedback alternative that came with C++17? Or any planned for C++20?

[Runnable example](https://www.onlinegdb.com/HyehrzUJw)

```cpp
template <typename State>
void callStateFunction(const State& state) {
  if constexpr (false) {
    state.method();
  } else {
    #warning The method State::method() was not implemented
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that it doesn't do exactly what you want to do but have you considered using [static_assert()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)? This would generate an error rather than a warning, though. Generating a warning for code that is correct is probably a bad idea in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution, I suppose, but...

If your compiler activate all warnings (`-Wall` for g++ and clang++, by example), you can substitute the `#warning` row with something that generate a warning.

By example, an unused (maybe with a talking name) variable.

I've tried with

```
template <typename State>
void callStateFunction(const State& state) {
  if constexpr (false) {
    state.method();
  } else {
    int method_not_implemented[sizeof(State)];
  }
}
```

and calling with a non-method value (`callStateFunction(1)`, by example), I get

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'void callStateFunction(const State&) [with State = int]':
prog.cc:13:23:   required from here
prog.cc:7:9: warning: unused variable 'method_not_implemented' [-Wunused-variable]
    7 |     int method_not_implemented[sizeof(State)];
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

from g++ (head 11.0.0) and

```
prog.cc:7:9: warning: unused variable 'method_not_implemented' [-Wunused-variable]
    int method_not_implemented[sizeof(State)];
        ^
prog.cc:13:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'callStateFunction<int>' requested here
   callStateFunction(1);
   ^
```

from clang++ (head 11.0.0)

I suggest that the unused variable depends from the template typename (`State`) otherwise, if I define a non-dependent variable as

```
int method_not_implement;
```

I get a warning from clang++

```
prog.cc:7:9: warning: unused variable 'method_not_implemented' [-Wunused-variable]
    int method_not_implemented;
        ^
```

also without calling the function with a non-method object.

Comment: Neat *hack*, but not something I'd want to rely on...

Comment: Not ideal, but this is pretty close. Maybe use some code that triggers warnings on all compilers, even with no warnings enabled. (If such code exists).

Comment: @JesperJuhl - I'm agree... unfortunately I can't imagine something that is very reliable.

Comment: @cigien - Not enabling warnings, I fear you can count only in errors, but the OP explicitly want only a warning. Unfortunately I'm agree with Jesper Juhl: not a reliable solution: seems to work with g++ and clang++ but we're not sure that works with every compiler.

Comment: I wished there was an alternative in the actual C++ specs due to the new compile-time capability of the language.
Sadly, this will not link the error to the actual method non implemented. I believe I should remove the compile-time check and enforce all functions to be implemented, and relying on the error which points to the State implementation: `main.cpp:9:11: error: ‘const class State’ has no member named ‘method’` while being templated.